# What is best way to convert existing installation of linux to puppet

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I have centos 6.4 running on aws on ec2.

I has installed all moudles , plugins , libraries etc myself manually.

Bow i want to convert that configuration into puupet.

But i don't know how to do because i always try to install things manually and then if things dont work then google it and try to fill the missing bits. Like symlink some shared lib to some folder etc.

Now i am confused to decode all those steps in puppet

Mian concern is getting php5.4 , mysql5.6 , python , djnago etc working.

Is there any easy way for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by learning puppet (read the manual and go through the online tutorial it's actually really helpful).

You'll need to document all the steps to configuring your server (think yum install, chmod, chown, editing files, starting services, running scripts).

Once you know what you need to do start to split things up into modules and build away. It really isn't all that hard so jump in and give it a go.

If you run I to a specific problem post a question.